# Can I omit or specify a "dummy" value for 'resolver' in my stack.yaml

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am using `stack.yaml` files in conjunction with a specified `--resolver` so that the `resolver` key in `stack.yaml` is (or should be) always ignored.

Is there a way to specify this fact in the `stack.yaml` itself? Or is there an idiom for expressing this there. I'd like to simply omit `resolver` from the file, but that's not allowed.

Comment: If you're always specifying the resolver using the `--resolver` flag, why not write the same resolver in `stack.yaml`? Are you switching resolvers frequently?

Comment: @theindigamer: It's not one-to-one and I'm trying to avoid (a) proliferation of files and (b) writing the same thing in several places. E.g., [I've got](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/tree/develop/travis-stacks) one `just_use_resolver.yaml`  and another `add_extra_dep_xyz.yaml`, and each of those applies to several different resolvers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not idiomatic to do things this way with stack, but you can put anything in the `resolver` field, and it will be ignored by stack if you supply the `--resolver` flag. For example:

```
$ cat stack.yaml
# stack.yaml
resolver: none
packages: []
extra-deps:
- tardis-0.2.0.0

$ stack repl
Unable to load custom resolver none from local file:
  /Users/dan/scratch/stack-no-resolver-test/none
Exception: InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: /Users/dan/scratch/stack-no-resolver-test/none"))

 $ stack --resolver lts-12.0 repl
...
Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
```

You just have to be able to understand that the "unable to load custom resolver none" error message, for your use case, means that you forgot to supply `--resolver` on the command line.

Comment: I'd be a little temped to document this using something like `resolver: chooseTheResolverOnTheCLI`. In such way, hopefully `stack` will produce a error hinting at the issue, if the user reads it carefully.